# What organization identifier to use for open source projects?

Tags: xcode, open-source, reverse-dns

Whenever you create a new project in Xcode, it asks for an organization identifier which should be in [reverse DNS notation](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/ConfiguringYourApp/ConfiguringYourApp.html). If my open source project has no domain (nor website), what should I use?

I was thinking I could somehow use the GitHub URL, but that doesn't seem like it'll work. For example say my code is at https://github.com/apple/swift, then the unique organization DNS would have to be something like `apple/com.github`, but `apple/` is not a valid part of a domain; and thus I would be left with `com.github`, which is belongs to another company.

I could theoretically use `com.github.apple` but this is a made up URL, and what's to say that it won't be a valid URL for some other organization in the future?

Comment: You can use the suggestion in the answer, you can also essentially make something up. There is no requirement that the org identifier refers to an actual domain or website, the (not very) important thing is you come up with something that avoids possible collisions or confusion and potentially lends itself to structured identification of multiple projects.

Answer (score 1):

Each GitHub user or organization can have their own set of [GitHub Pages](https://pages.github.com), which, among other things, gives you a domain such as `apple.github.io`.

Follow the [tutorial](https://pages.github.com), and choose to create a "User or organization site." Once you are done, you can use the domain as a company identifier in reverse DNS notation: **io.github.*username***